# AngularJS cookies issue

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I am using AngularJS cookies to maintain user session. But I am facing issues with cookies.

I have created multiple cookies, Out of that one cookie is session cookie and other cookies are created when stay sign in is ticked.And when I delete cookies on logout , if stay sign in is not ticked (only session cookie exists) then other cookies are also created as session cookies.

My code is as following:

```
 if(remember_me)
    {
        console.log("remember_me");
        $cookies.put("remember_me",remember_me,{expires:moment().add(5, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),path:"/"});
        $cookies.put("remember_me_data",JSON.stringify({email_id:user.email_id,org_id:user.org_id,auto_login:true}),{expires:moment().add(5, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),path:"/"});
        $cookies.put("cookie_date",moment().utc().unix(),{expires:moment().add(5, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),path:"/"});
        $cookies.put("logged_user",JSON.stringify({email_id:user.email_id,org_id:user.org_id,user_id:user.user_id}),{path:"/"});
    } 
    else
    {   
        console.log("not remember");
        if(user)
        {
            //$localStorage.logged_user=JSON.stringify({email_id:user.email_id,org_id:user.org_id});
            $cookies.put("logged_user",JSON.stringify({email_id:user.email_id,org_id:user.org_id,user_id:user.user_id}),{path:"/"});


        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share some of your code regading that how you are generating cookie.